# Programmatically open context menu using UI automation?

Tags: c#, automation, contextmenu, routedevent

I'm trying to implement a right click context menu using UI automation.  Since UI automation does not have a native right click pattern I am adding an ExpandCollapse provider to the listview's AutomationPeer class and mapping the expand and collapse to opening and closing the context menu.

My question, is there a better method of invoking the context menu that doesn't involve trying to instantiate a class with a private constructor?  I can't use SendKeys with Shift-F10.  I'd like to use the PopupControlService but that is tagged as internal.

My awful workaround:

```
public class MyListViewAutomationPeer : ListViewAutomationPeer, IExpandCollapseProvider
{

    public MyListViewAutomationPeer(MyListView owner)
        : base(owner){}

    public override object GetPattern(PatternInterface patternInterface)
    {
        if (patternInterface == PatternInterface.ExpandCollapse)
        {
            return this;
        }
        return base.GetPattern(patternInterface);
    }

    public void Expand()
    {
        MyListView owner = (MyListView)Owner;

        //**********************
        //Ouch!!! What a hack
        //**********************

        //ContextMenuEventArgs is a sealed class, with private constructors
        //Instantiate it anyway ...
        ContextMenuEventArgs cmea = (ContextMenuEventArgs)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(ContextMenuEventArgs));
        cmea.RoutedEvent = MyListView.ContextMenuOpeningEvent;
        cmea.Source = owner;

        //This will fire any developer code that is bound to the OpenContextMenuEvent
        owner.RaiseEvent(cmea);

        //The context menu didn't open because this is a hack, so force it open
        owner.ContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Center;
        owner.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (UIElement)owner;
        owner.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I too am struggling with the same issue. As a work around i am using the mouse_event function using user32.dll and performing the right click after getting the X, Y coordinates of the clickable area.

This is not a good method as the X , Y coordinates of screen vary with the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a good start, but you should use Activator directly to create the `ContextMenuEventArgs` class. (What you have is using something that internally uses the reflection. You should just use it directly.)

Also, for completeness, you should check the `Handled` property before actually opening the menu to be consistent with the expected behavior.

I've illustrated both things below.

```
var owner = (MyListView)Owner;

// Construct the ContextMenuEventArgs
var constructorArgs = new object[] { owner, true };

var contextMenuEventArgs = (ContextMenuEventArgs)Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(ContextMenuEventArgs),
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    null,
    constructorArgs,
    null);

// Configure and use as needed
contextMenuEventArgs.RoutedEvent = FrameworkElement.ContextMenuOpeningEvent;
owner.RaiseEvent(contextMenuEventArgs);

if (contextMenuEventArgs.Handled)
    return;

owner.ContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Center;
owner.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (UIElement)owner;
owner.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
```

I took it a step further and created a global function I can call that simplifies the above calling of non-public constructors.  Here's the function...

```
public static class PrivateActivator {

    public static T CreateInstance<T>(params object?[] arguments) { 

        var item = Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(T),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null,
            arguments,
            null);

        if (item is T typedItem)
            return typedItem;
        else
            throw new Exception("Cannot create type");
    }
}
```

And here's how to use it...

```
var contextMenuEventArgs = PrivateActivator.CreateInstance<ContextMenuEventArgs>(AssociatedObject, true);
```