# Raising ContextMenuClosing event manually

Tags: wpf, routed-events

I'm deriving from ContextMenu and inside the derived class I need to raise the ContextMenuClosing event manually. I tried the following two ways:

```
// On runtime tells me it can't convert from  
// "System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs" to 
// "System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenuEventArgs"
RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ContextMenuClosingEvent));

// Second attempt: On compile time tells me,
// there's no constructor for ContextMenuEventArgs
OnContextMenuClosing(new ContextMenuEventArgs());
```

I'm new to RoutedEvents, can someone please help me how to raise the ContextMenuClosing event manually? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008399/programmatically-open-context-menu-using-ui-automation) the poster shows code in which he seems to be able to instantiate ContextMenuEventArgs even though its constructor is private